# Why mkdir fails with different base images in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I'am using Linus CentOS 7 and my Docker version is 19.03.8. When I try to build an image using a base image from Docker-hub its all good, but when I try to use private repository I receive an error.

My dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM <IMAGENAME>:<TAG> AS base
ENV MY_VAR=/home/test/installs
RUN mkdir -p $MY_VAR ....
```

The remaining is irrelevant for now, since I got error saying

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/vmtest' : Permission denied
```

As I said, I tested it with image from Docker-hub and this worked just fine.. To use the private repo I've modified the **daemon.json** file adding this

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
}
```

Is there some connection between those or if somebody has an idea I would be really thankful.

Comment: Apparently the user in the base image does not have permissions. Try running `User root` before the the instruction that produces the permission denied. Then you can switch the user back to the propper setting

Comment: The base image can do things like set an alternate user and change filesystem permissions; without knowing anything about the base image it's impossible to say what's going on.

Comment: It's a good practice to specify the user your Docker image will use. This also solves your problem as a user directory will be created.

Comment: @DavidMaze, this was it, the base image has its own user and messes up some stuff, I would have to investigate some more but this was a very good tip!